# Virtualenv gives different versions for different os

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am working on a django project on two separate systems, Debian Jessie and Mac El Capitan. The project is hosted on github where both systems will pull from or push to.

However, I noticed that on my Debian, when I run `python --version`, it gives me `Python 3.4.2` but on my Mac, it gives me `Python 2.7.10` despite being in the same virtual environment. Moreover, when I run `django-admin --version` on my Debian, it gives me `1.10` while on my Mac, `1.8.3`.

This happens even when I freshly clone the projects from github and run the commands.

Why is it that the virtual environment does not keep the same version of python and django?

Comment: You need to explicitly tell Virtualenv what Python executable to use.  If you don't specify one, it will just use the default/system one.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Even in the virtual environment? You mean I need to specify like `bin/python command`? I thought the point of a virtual environment is to isolate my system's python.

Comment: No, the point of a virtual environment is to isolate the packages you install.

Comment: have you activated the environments before running python? just having the right folder structure sadly does not do it. (See https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#activate-script )

Comment: @janbrohl Yes I activated the environments.

Comment: Use `virtualenv -p python3` on the mac

Comment: @dunder Although I did not use that, I did use `python3 -m virtualenv venv` to create my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you understand that virtual environments can't be transferred easily from machine to machine. It's common to use the

```
pip freeze
```

command and store its output in a file called `requirements.txt`. Then anyone else can rebuild your envirnment on their machine by running

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When you create a new virtual environment you can say which Python interpreter you want to use with the `-p` or `--python` switch, which should be followed by the path to the correct executable.

I'd personally recommend against modifying the system Python in any way, because system maintenance routines often rely on its integrity. It's relatively simple to install new copies for Python 2 and 3 somewhere like `/usr/local/bin` (Mac users often use `brew` for this) and have virtual environments that rely on different Python interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Oliver and @Daniel's comments that lead me to the answer why it did not work.

I started the virtual environment on my Debian with python 3. `virtualenv` made the virtual environment but it was specifically for Debian.

When I used it for mac, since it could not run the python executable in the virtual environment (since it is only compatible with Debian), hence, it used my Mac's system python, which is Python 2.7.10.

In summary, as `virtualenv` uses the python executable on the system, when the python executable is run on another system, it will not work.